# Background extending out from responsive image when too small to reach browser edge?

Tags: html, image, css

Trying my hand at some responsive design and got images to scale well enough and never so big that it gets cut off by the edge of the browser; however, when it's so small that it doesn't quite (or even remotely) reach the browser edge it doesn't look too great in my opinion, in particularly when it's between full size and just the same size as text paragraphs.

I want to give these responsive images a darker background that always extends out the left of the image all the way to the edge of the browser and is the same height as the image.

Without background:

[image]

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

Since these images are responsive and of varying aspect ratios as well they never have the same height so I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

P.S. I've tried border-left but that pushes the image itself to the right (absolute positioning didn't help) and outline can't be assigned to just one side.

Comment: Example of full-width image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLGEh.jpg (wasn't allowed more than two links above)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understand your question clearly. Anyway I have come up with some idea about your requirement. Check my fiddle below for the sample. I didn't concentrate in the responsive area, but it will give some idea on your way.

```
#header, #bottom
{
color:#fff;
text-align:justify;
padding-left:30%;
}
 #content
{
background-color:#000;
text-align:right;
}
```

[**Have a Fiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Np7/)